# Image stored in directory with getExternalFilesDir() not visible in phone gallery even after MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()

Tags: android, android-image, android-9.0-pie, android-storage, android-mediascanner

I'm saving the image captured by the user in the app specific external directory with `getExternalFilesDir()` and want this image to be also visible in gallery to the user. As per the docs any media *(image in my case)* saved in these directory is not directly visible to MediaScanner, but we can still make them explicitly visible to MediaScanner using `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()`.

I am following the same steps as mentioned above, after I save the image in directory I explicitly call `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` but still nothing happens, image is stored in app specific external directory but not visible in gallery?

```kotlin
//getting app specific external directory
val mediaStorageDir = File(app.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES))
val file = File("${mediaStorageDir.path}${File.separator}front_image.jpg")

//saving file
val bos = FileOutputStream(file)
val original = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(this, 0, size)
original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos)

//after saving file
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(file.absolutePath), null, null)
```

**I am testing on Android Version: 9 | Custom OS: Funtouch OS_9.2 | Model: vivo 1921**

Answer (score 0):

Yes getExternalFilesDir() is an app specific directory. The MediaStore scanner will not index it and hence Gallery apps are unaware of your images. Thats how it is intended to be. –

Comment: But i am calling `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` explicitly. Will this have no effect if the image is in `getExternalFilesDir()` ??

Comment: I'm now inserting the image in MediaStore with `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage()` and then calling `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` which seems to work !!

Comment: insertImage method is now deprecated